# Spring Boot execute method on startup and set informations into session

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to set some informations like page title in HttpSession on my spring boot project startup, but i have no idea how to do this the best way.

The page title have to be read out from my database.

How i can execute a method on startup and set informations in a HttpSession?

Comment: The HttpSession is created when the user connects for the first time. It does not make sense to poulate the HttpSession on startup. Can you tell more about what you want to do?

Comment: You can't. A session is linked to a specific user using your app. When your app starts, there is no user at all yet. So there is no session. It makes no sense to store information that is global to the app in a session. Store it in some Spring singleton bean.